# Mongoose: Find from reference object document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to search data from collection.

Model for 'USER' collection:

```
var model = new Schema({
    userName: String,
    password: String
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('user', model);
```

Model for 'BLOG'

```
var model = new Schema({
    title: String,
    createdBy: { type: Object, ref: 'user' }
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('blog', model);
```

My search code for blog collection:

```
objModel.find({ 'createdBy.userName': 'test_user' }).populate('createdBy')
.exec(function (err, lstBlog) {
    console.log(lstBlog.length);
});
```

But not able to get any record. There are 2 record in database for 'test_user'.

Comment: `createdBy` should be of type `ObjectId`, not `Object`.

Comment: Then error comes: 'TypeError: Undefined type `ObjectId`'

Comment: It should be `Schema.Types.ObjectId`. Read more about it here https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html

Comment: error solve but still 0 record return.

Comment: When you use populate, the query result contains the joined results. So `createdBy.userName` matches nothing. Read more about populate to understand how it works https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html. It shows how to query while populating.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make some changes in your 'BLOG' model :

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var SCHEMA = mongoose.Schema;

var model = new Schema({
    title: String,
    createdBy: { type: SCHEMA.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'user' }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('blog', model);
```

and then the following query will work

```
blog.find({}).populate(
      {
        path: 'createdBy',
        match: {'userName': 'test_user' }
      }
    ).exec(function (err, lstBlog) {
    console.log(lstBlog.length);
});;
```